# How to transform capitalize name in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to have the name in `print("\nThank you, " + name + ".")` where I can put in however and whatever I want, with either lowercase and uppercase. I tried adding both `.lower()` and `.upper()` at the end of that and as well after `name`, but it didn't work. Any solutions? Example down below.

```
def welcomeGame():
   name=input("Hello! Welcome to my game. What is your first name? ")

   while True:
      if name.istitle() and name.isalpha():
         break

      print("\nI'm sorry " + name + ", names are only allowed to contain letters, and with the first capitalized letter of your name.")
      name=input("Please re-enter your name: ")

   print("\nThank you, " + name + ".")
   print("\nYou will start off with 0 points, let's play!\n")  
welcomeGame()
```

How I want it to look.

```
Hello! Welcome to my game. What is your first name? bEn
I'm sorry bEn, names are only allowed to contain letters, and with the first capitalized letter of your name.
Please re-enter your name: bEN

# the actual output after it asks to re-enter your name:
I'm sorry bEN, names are only allowed to contain letters, and with the first capitalized letter of your name. 
Please re-enter your name.

# how I actually want the output to look like after it asks to re-enter your name:
Thank you, Ben.
```

Comment: Not sure what you want, but have you tried `name.lower().capitalize()`? (or `.title()` if you want each word capitalized)

Comment: @Grismar, when I do that, it proceeds with the ```I'm sorry bEN, names are only allowed to contain letters, and with the first capitalized letter of your name.``` message instead of saying ```Thank you, Ben.```

Comment: I didn't get your question , if the user writes "bEN" , whether it should accept it or not ? or you just want to print 'bEN" as "Ben"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use title() function.

```
def welcomeGame():
   name=input("Hello! Welcome to my game. What is your first name? ")

   while True:
      if name.istitle() and name.isalpha():
         break

      print("\nI'm sorry " + name + ", names are only allowed to contain letters, and 
with the first capitalized letter of your name.")
      name=input("Please re-enter your name: ").title()

   print("\nThank you, " + name + ".")
   print("\nYou will start off with 0 points, let's play!\n")  
welcomeGame()
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, however - I only would like it to do that after it asks to re-enter my name.

Comment: Use the title() in second input line. Just changed the code. Please check

Comment: Thanks dude, that worked! It won't let me accept your answer for another three minutes so I'll check back in a bit.